# Unable to Git Pull to update my Git local repo

Tags: git, pull

I removed a file in my local Git repo.
I want the file back by updating my Git repo.

I run the following unsuccessfully

```
git pull
```

It says upToDate, but I did not get the newest file.
The public repo at github does not use SVN, so the problem cannot be SVN.

**How can you update your local Git repo**, such that you get your removed File back to your computer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

August has the probably best way for your problem.

You could also revert to the last version you pulled:

```
git reset --hard
```

Answer (score 8):

If it hasn't been committed yet:

```
 git checkout path/to/file
```

Comment: @SimpleQuestions: The path should be a relative path to the file in your local repository, e.g. "git checkout theFile". You may also specify the revision "git checkout master~1 theFile". See the examples at http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html