# Unable to update my Local Git repo based on SVN

Tags: svn, git

I know the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842915/unable-to-git-pull-to-update-my-git-local-repo) which command updates files for me at my current version number, not the newest files.

I run unsuccessfully at a Google-code project's trunk

```
git svn update
```

and I get

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Already at toplevel, but .git not found
 at /opt/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 235
```

I have not updated the repo for a month. A new version is released. I was last time able to update the repo by the above command.

**How can you update a repo based on Svn by Git?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Locally, are you in a folder that was a checkout of the SVN repository, that was made by Git?  Or is it a checkout that was made by SVN?

If I understand what you are trying to do, get the latest updates in an SVN repository, using Git...  than this command

```
  git svn update
```

does not exist according to [these docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn).  You should initialize a local Git version of an SVN repository by pulling the source using a command similar to:

```
  git svn clone http://code.google.com/blah -T trunk -b branches -t tags
```

... and then to get the latest updates in the trunk folder, you should:

```
  cd trunk
  git svn rebase
```

The examples on that documentation link are quite helpful.